# Hashing a string in php

Tags: php, hash

This is the hashed output "bWNgAQW2FLc"
I want to possibly hash a specific string into that. Is there any method or coding that can possibly do the work?

Thank you very much for the replies!

PS: I do not know what hash type is that in the first place

Comment: Do you know what the original string was?

Comment: @user3783243 its developered1

Comment: No hashing functions maps back to that. https://3v4l.org/IfDGv

Comment: Can you give some context? Any salt-based hashing will generate different hashes for the same input.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you very much for the effort! Do you possibly know a way of coding a function that could hash/encrypt like that

Comment: It is infinite. Anything can convert a string to something else.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this Using Simple inbuild Hash Function Available in PHP

```
<?php
  echo hash('ripemd160', 'Your text goes here');
?>
```

Source http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! Do you possibly know how can I hash a string same as that output on my post.

Comment: Give me the string, and I'll figure out the hash used, can you?

Comment: The string was "developered1"

Comment: All you need is the right key... do you have a key, or salt used, I've written an encryption and decryption module... I need a key t run it

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! I unfortunately don't have the key or salt used...

Comment: It was Built with Base64, In a bit, I'll find the complete code.

Comment: Lol', it was custome build crypto', I'm sorry hope you find help soon,